# Japan Visa Validity

Tags: visas, japan

I have a multiple entry Japan visa valid for 5 years and for 30 days of stay duration.
I went to Japan last year and they put an initial stamp on my passport with Date of permit as 09 Nov 2018 , until 09 Dec 2018 and Duration 30 days

But i departed within 12 days so then there is a departure stamp for 20th Nov 2018.

Now i am not sure if i can still use this visa for remaining 18 days or is this visa entirely used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a multiple entry visa, so you can use it as many times as you want (while it is valid), and you will have 30 days each time.

Comment: Thanks for response. So in multiple entry visa, 30 days are applicable for each entry and its not cummulative number of days?

Comment: @TravellingJuggernaut Correct.  In many countries including Japan, the visa gives you the right to enter the country during a given period (for you 5 years), and you are given an entry permit valid for a number of days (30) on arrival.

Comment: @jpatokal Thanks a lot for clarification